# Read a header of a https request inside a proxy

Tags: ssl, proxy, tcp

I have implemented a custom proxy server to routing my network traffics. I have two or more browsers and installed a browser extension in each browser. The browser extension will append two different HTTP headers for all HTTP requests.

Showcase:-

```
----------Browser1 Request-------------
| // GET https://google.com/ HTTP 1.1 |
| // Browser: 1                       |-----------|
| // ...                              |           |
--------------------------------------            |                       |-------|
                                                  |---------------------->|       |===> VPN1
                                                                          | Proxy |
                                                  |---------------------->|       |===> VPN2
----------Browser2 Request-------------           |                       |-------|
| // GET https://google.com/ HTTP 1.1 |           |
| // Browser: 2                       |-----------|
| // ...                              |
--------------------------------------
```

When I use a http URL I can read the header value:-

```
GET http://google.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.66.0\r\nAccept: */*\r\nProxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\r\nBrowser:1\r\n\r\n
```

But when I use a https URL I can not read the header value:-

```
\x16\x03\x01\x02\0\x01\0\x01\xfc\x03\...
```

Thanks in advance for any solution or any alternative solution to accomplish it.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP headers are part of the actual request payload, therefore when HTTP is run over TLS (https), the payload is encrypted.

If you want to intercept https traffic, you need to install your own certificate on the proxy and browser system. This way the proxy can act as a man-in-the middle entity, seeing all the encrypted traffic between browser and server.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what exactly you browser extension does and what you are exactly trying to achieve. But if you want to distinguish the browser at the proxy then this will not work for HTTPS if you add an header to the final HTTP request - because this one will be encrypted with TLS. This exactly is what you see, i.e. `\x16\x03\x01...` is the start of a TLS handshake.

A better approach would be to use proxy authentication. In this case each user (and thus the browser) has to authenticate against the proxy. The necessary information are send inside the [Proxy-Authenticate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Proxy-Authorization) header - both for a plain HTTP request and also for the CONNECT request which requests a tunnel through the proxy for HTTPS.

The advantage of using proxy authentication is also that it is actually authentication of the client what you want, it is the standard way to authenticate the client to the proxy, it is well supported in browsers but also command-line clients and it does not need any special browser extensions.